# How do I delete columns from numerous tables/dataset collections with Python?

Tags: python, pandas

Essentially, I need to know how to change this dataset collection output that is shown here:

```
   A  B  C
0  2  1  5
1  3  2  3
2  1  3  4
3  4  4  4

   A  B  C
0  2  1  5
1  3  2  3
2  1  3  4
3  4  4  4
4  5  5  5

   A  B  C  D
0  2  1  5  1
1  3  2  3  2
2  1  3  4  3
3  4  4  4  4
4  5  5  5  5
```

to this dataset collection, keep in mind that I essentially am deleting column B in the first and second tables:

```
   A  C
0  2  5
1  3  3
2  1  4
3  4  4

   A  C
0  2  5
1  3  3
2  1  4
3  4  4
4  5  5

   A  B  C  D
0  2  1  5  1
1  3  2  3  2
2  1  3  4  3
3  4  4  4  4
4  5  5  5  5
```

With this code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [2,3,1],
                  'B': [1,2,3],
                  'C': [5,3,4]})
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [4],
                  'B': [4],
                  'C': [4]})
df = df.append(df1)
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
print(df)

df.loc[df.last_valid_index() + 1] = [5,5,5]
print()
print(df)

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'D': [1,2,3,4,5]})

df = pd.DataFrame.join(df,df2)
print()
print(df)
```

Thanks in advance for any help. Please let me know if you need more clarification on this issue. (I am typing this because it is giving me errors with all of the code and just a bit of regular text.)

Comment: it's unclear what is the input and output exactly and in which step you need help

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by: "Essentially, I need to know how to change this dataset collection".  What do you want to change, what do you need help with?  **DO NOT** post images of code, links to code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question.

Comment: @mozway Here's the updates.

Comment: @itprorh66 I made the requested corrections.

Comment: From what I can discern, you want to drop column B from the first 2 dataframes and do nothing to the third.   Is this correct?

Comment: @itprorh66 That is right.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all you want to do is drop a column from a dataframe you can easily do this as follows:
given the following:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [2,3,1,4],
                  'B': [1,2,3, 4],
                  'C': [5,3,4, 4]})
```

produces df:

```
A   B   C
0   2   1   5
1   3   2   3
2   1   3   4
3   4   4   4
```

You can drop Column 'B' by:

```
df.drop('B', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Which results in:

```
    A   C
0   2   5
1   3   3
2   1   4
3   4   4
​
```